# Longest Path algorithm Sotring the path find

Tags: java, path, path-finding

Currently i have a functioning algorithm for finding the longest path. but when i try to print out the path it instead print out all the path it took to find the Longest Path. How should i fix this ?

I tired to take out the backtrack which leads to a wrong answer but way less outputs (about 400 less in this case). Or should i make another ArrayList for storing the correct path? How should i do that since the codes runs thought all possibilities. Or Should i modify the code in some way ?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Point;

class Main
{
    // M x N matrix
    private static final int M = 10;
    private static final int N = 10;
    static ArrayList<Point> Path = new ArrayList<Point>();

    // check if it is possible to go to position (x, y) from
    // current position. The function returns false if the cell
    // has value 0 or it is already visited.
    private static boolean isSafe(int mat[][], int visited[][], int x, int y) {
        if (mat[x][y] == 0 || visited[x][y] != 0)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    // if not a valid position, return false
    private static boolean isValid(int x, int y) {
        if (x < M && y < N && x >= 0 && y >= 0)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    // Find Longest Possible Route in a Matrix mat from source
    // cell (0, 0) to destination cell (x, y)
    // 'max_dist' stores length of longest path from source to
    // destination found so far and 'dist' maintains length of path from
    // source cell to the current cell (i, j)
    public static int findLongestPath(int mat[][], int visited[][], int i, int j, int x, int y, int max_dist,
            int dist) {
        // if destination not possible from current cell
        if (mat[i][j] == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        // if destination is found, update max_dist
        if (i == x && j == y) {
            return Integer.max(dist, max_dist);
        }

        // set (i, j) cell as visited
        visited[i][j] = 1;

        // go to bottom cell
        if (isValid(i + 1, j) && isSafe(mat, visited, i + 1, j)) {
            max_dist = findLongestPath(mat, visited, i + 1, j, x, y, max_dist, dist + 1);
        }

        // go to right cell
        if (isValid(i, j + 1) && isSafe(mat, visited, i, j + 1)) {
            max_dist = findLongestPath(mat, visited, i, j + 1, x, y, max_dist, dist + 1);
        }

        // go to top cell
        if (isValid(i - 1, j) && isSafe(mat, visited, i - 1, j)) {
            max_dist = findLongestPath(mat, visited, i - 1, j, x, y, max_dist, dist + 1);
        }

        // go to left cell
        if (isValid(i, j - 1) && isSafe(mat, visited, i, j - 1)) {
            max_dist = findLongestPath(mat, visited, i, j - 1, x, y, max_dist, dist + 1);
        }

        // Backtrack - Remove (i, j) from visited matrix
        visited[i][j] = 0;

        Point temp = new Point(i, j);
        Path.add(temp);

        return max_dist;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // input matrix
        int mat[][] =
        {
                { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
                { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 },
                { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
                { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 },
                { 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
                { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 }
        };

        // construct a matrix to keep track of visited cells
        int[][] visited= new int[N][N];

        // (0,0) are the source cell coordinates and (5, 7) are the
        // destination cell coordinates
        int max_dist = findLongestPath(mat, visited, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, 0);

        System.out.println("Maximum length path is " + max_dist);
        
        Collections.reverse(Path);
        int i = 1;
        for (Point point : Path) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + point.toString());
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning "int", you can return an object which contains this int + information on the path made !

Here is a similar example from another exercise but with the same goal :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class LabiLab {
    static int f = 0;
    static int sum = 0;
    static String direction = "";
    static int[][] gridarray = {
            {0, 21, 20, 5, 25, 25, 35, 15},
            {12, 26, 43, 29, 15, 26, 15, 12},
            {7, 18, 23, 28, 36, 32, 12, 18},
            {43, 34, 35, 18, 25, 18, 21, 25},
            {32, 41, 23, 9, 21, 17, 24, 14},
            {12, 9, 20, 42, 9, 19, 26, 22},
            {30, 17, 17, 35, 14, 25, 14, 21},
            {15, 21, 37, 24, 19, 15, 35, 15}};

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LabiPath bestLabiPath = bestPath(0, 0);
        System.out.println(bestLabiPath.steps);
        System.out.println(bestLabiPath.distance);
        System.out.println(bestLabiPath.distancePerStep);
    }

    static LabiPath bestPath(int i, int j){
        if (i==7 && j==7) return new LabiPath(gridarray[i][j], Arrays.asList("X"), Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(gridarray[i][j])));
        else if (i == 7) {
            LabiPath labiPathToRight = bestPath(i, j + 1).copyWithStepAndDistance("R", gridarray[i][j]);
            return labiPathToRight;
        }
        else if (j == 7) {
            LabiPath labiPathToDown = bestPath(i + 1, j).copyWithStepAndDistance("D", gridarray[i][j]);
            return labiPathToDown;
        }
        else {
            LabiPath labiPathToRight = bestPath(i, j + 1).copyWithStepAndDistance("R", gridarray[i][j]);
            LabiPath labiPathToDown = bestPath(i + 1, j).copyWithStepAndDistance("D", gridarray[i][j]);
            return labiPathToDown.compareTo(labiPathToRight) < 0 ? labiPathToDown : labiPathToRight;
        }
    }
}

class LabiPath implements Comparable {
    int distance;
    List<String> steps ;
    List<String> distancePerStep ;


    public LabiPath(int distance, List<String> steps, List<String> distancePerStep) {
        this.distance = distance;
        this.steps = steps;
        this.distancePerStep = distancePerStep;
    }

    public LabiPath copyWithStepAndDistance(String step, int distanceForStep){
        int newDistance = this.distance + distanceForStep;
        ArrayList<String> stepsCopy = new ArrayList<>(this.steps);
        List<String> distancePerStepCopy = new ArrayList<>(distanceForStep);
        LabiPath newLabiPath = new LabiPath(newDistance, stepsCopy,  distancePerStepCopy);
        newLabiPath.steps.add(0, step);
        newLabiPath.distancePerStep.add(0, String.valueOf(distanceForStep));
        return newLabiPath;
    }


    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof LabiPath) {
            return distance - ((LabiPath) o).distance;
        }
        else throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
import java.util.*;

import java.awt.Point;

class Main

{
    // M x N matrix

    private static final int M = 10;

    private static final int N = 10;

    static ArrayList<Point> Path = new ArrayList<Point>();

    // check if it is possible to go to position (x, y) from

    // current position. The function returns false if the cell

    // has value 0 or it is already visited.

    private static boolean isSafe(int mat[][], int visited[][], int x, int y) {

        if (mat[x][y] == 0 || visited[x][y] != 0)

            return false;

        return true;

    }

    // if not a valid position, return false

    private static boolean isValid(int x, int y) {

        if (x < M && y < N && x >= 0 && y >= 0)

            return true;

        return false;

    }

    //deepcopy arraylist
    private static ArrayList<Point> deepCopy(ArrayList<Point> array){
        
        ArrayList<Point> newArray = new ArrayList<Point>(); 

        for (Point point : array) {
            newArray.add(point);
        }

        return newArray;
    }

    // Find Longest Possible Route in a Matrix mat from source

    // cell (0, 0) to destination cell (x, y)

    // 'max_dist' stores length of longest path from source to

    // destination found so far and 'dist' maintains length of path from

    // source cell to the current cell (i, j)

    public static int findLongestPath(int mat[][], int visited[][], int i, int j, int x, int y, int max_dist, int dist,
        ArrayList<Point> path) {

        // if destination not possible from current cell

        if (mat[i][j] == 0) {

            return 0;

        }

        //creating new point
        Point temp = new Point(i, j);
        
        //adding new point to path
        path.add(temp);

        // if destination is found, update max_dist

        if (i == x && j == y) {

            //updating Path with new longer path found
            if(dist > max_dist){
                Path = deepCopy(path);
            }

            //backtracking step
            path.remove(temp);

            return Integer.max(dist, max_dist);

        }

        // set (i, j) cell as visited

        visited[i][j] = 1;


        // go to bottom cell

        if (isValid(i + 1, j) && isSafe(mat, visited, i + 1, j)) {

            max_dist = findLongestPath(mat, visited, i + 1, j, x, y, max_dist, dist + 1, path);

        }

        // go to right cell

        if (isValid(i, j + 1) && isSafe(mat, visited, i, j + 1)) {

            max_dist = findLongestPath(mat, visited, i, j + 1, x, y, max_dist, dist + 1, path);

        }

        // go to top cell

        if (isValid(i - 1, j) && isSafe(mat, visited, i - 1, j)) {

            max_dist = findLongestPath(mat, visited, i - 1, j, x, y, max_dist, dist + 1, path);

        }

        // go to left cell

        if (isValid(i, j - 1) && isSafe(mat, visited, i, j - 1)) {

            max_dist = findLongestPath(mat, visited, i, j - 1, x, y, max_dist, dist + 1, path);

        }

        // Backtrack - Remove (i, j) from visited matrix

        visited[i][j] = 0;

        // Backtracking - Removing current point from path

        path.remove(temp);

        return max_dist;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {

        // input matrix

        int map[][] =

        {

                { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },

                { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 },

                { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },

                { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },

                { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },

                { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },

                { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 },

                { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 },

                { 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },

                { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 }

        };

        // construct a matrix to keep track of visited cells

        int[][] visited= new int[N][N];

        //newPath will contain paths while traversing the search space 

        ArrayList<Point> newPath = new ArrayList<Point>();

        // (0,0) are the source cell coordinates and (5, 7) are the

        // destination cell coordinates

        int max_dist = findLongestPath(map, visited, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, 0, newPath);

        System.out.println("Maximum length path is " + max_dist);

        
        Collections.reverse(Path);

        int i = 1;

        for (Point point : Path) {

            System.out.println(i + " " + point.toString());

            i++;

        }

    }

}
```

**Sample Output**

```
1 java.awt.Point[x=5,y=7]
2 java.awt.Point[x=5,y=8]
3 java.awt.Point[x=4,y=8]
4 java.awt.Point[x=4,y=7]
5 java.awt.Point[x=4,y=6]
6 java.awt.Point[x=5,y=6]
7 java.awt.Point[x=5,y=5]
8 java.awt.Point[x=5,y=4]
9 java.awt.Point[x=4,y=4]
10 java.awt.Point[x=3,y=4]
11 java.awt.Point[x=2,y=4]
12 java.awt.Point[x=2,y=5]
13 java.awt.Point[x=1,y=5]
14 java.awt.Point[x=1,y=4]
15 java.awt.Point[x=0,y=4]
16 java.awt.Point[x=0,y=3]
17 java.awt.Point[x=0,y=2]
18 java.awt.Point[x=1,y=2]
19 java.awt.Point[x=2,y=2]
20 java.awt.Point[x=3,y=2]
21 java.awt.Point[x=4,y=2]
22 java.awt.Point[x=4,y=3]
23 java.awt.Point[x=5,y=3]
24 java.awt.Point[x=5,y=2]
25 java.awt.Point[x=5,y=1]
26 java.awt.Point[x=5,y=0]
27 java.awt.Point[x=4,y=0]
28 java.awt.Point[x=3,y=0]
29 java.awt.Point[x=2,y=0]
30 java.awt.Point[x=1,y=0]
31 java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0]
```